# How to make SQLAlchemy recognize the custom types already defined in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm recently using **SQLAlchemy** and I get the following error when I try to connect to an existing **PostgreSQL** database.

code:

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_url, case_sensitive=False)
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
my_table = sqlalchemy.Table('tbl_my_table', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

error:

```sh
../sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/base.py:3133: SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'type_coordinate' of column 'position'
  "Did not recognize type '%s' of column '%s'" % (attype, name)
```

the error refers to a custom type defined by me:

```sql
CREATE TYPE TYPE_COORDINATE AS (
  x           INTEGER,
  y           INTEGER,
  t           INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE tbl_my_table (
  id          INTEGER          PRIMARY KEY,
  position    TYPE_COORDINATE  DEFAULT (0, 0, 0)
);
```

The real problem arises when I try to access to "position" in a query.

How do I make sqlalchemy recognize the TYPE_COORDINATE type?